# Exclusion script for Journey Builder send

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, exclusion-script

I have two emails with identical content - one is used in one journey, the other in a second journey. However, I want to be sure that if a person happens to enter both journeys within a short timeframe, they do not receive both. Would it be possible to do this via an exclusion script? (I.e. For the send of Email1, have an exclusion script that excludes anyone that has received Email2 within the past 30days. And then vice versa in the other journey).

If it is, what would be that script to use? I've seen ones that look up info in DEs etc. but nothing that can look at system data for specific email sends.
If it's not possible, what would be your suggestion on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a script to exclude emails within a certain timeframe based on the system time. I believe this will be useful in creating a script for you, I will place the script and description of the steps below.

Hour based raise error that prevents sends at a specified time

##### Step 1

###### Create the time variables

These will hold the various different parts of time data you will need to isolate an appropriate hour.

```
VAR @hour, @flag, @servertime, @localtime
```

Note: Flag is optional, but if you were planning to record the injections outside of business hours this could be a way to.

##### Step 2

###### Set the server time

You will want to first set your server time variable as mentioned above to the current server time using the `Now()` function

```
%%[
VAR @hour, @flag, @servertime, @localtime

SET @servertime = NOW()
```

##### Step 3

The next part is 100% optional, but you can set the server time to match the local time using the `SystemDateToLocalDate` function.
I am currently in the progress of testing this in various VPN locations.
It may be 100% useless

```
SET @localtime = SystemDateToLocalDate(@servertime)
```

##### Step 4

We want to isolate the hour value from this date.
You can do this by using the `datepart` function  and selecting `H` for hour.

Note: As you may have already guessed this works for Year as `Y`, Day as `D`, Month as `M` Minute as `MI` , etc.

```
SET @hour = datePart(@servertime, "H")
```

##### Step 5

Now that the hour is isolated it will return a value of 1-24.

The stipulation as to what timeframe you would like to prevent sends is up to you.

Using an `IF` statement we are able to isolate any values greater than any number = to 6 AND any hour value less than 18(6pm)

This creates a 12 on/off cycle

```
IF @Hour >= 6 AND @hour <= 18 THEN
```

##### Step 6 (Optional)

Set the prementioned flag in step 1 to the `true` value

```
SET @flag = True
```

##### Step 7

Now that all the parameters are set the error and error value will still need to be raised

The true value at the end indicates if the journey will shut down after this error is raised or will the journey continue to the next subscriber.

```
ELSE RaiseError ("Outside operating business hours", true)
```

##### Step 8

```
ENDIF
]%%
```

---

Below is the full set of code.

```
%%[ 
VAR @hour, @flag, @servertime, @localtime 
SET @servertime = NOW() 
SET @localtime = SystemDateToLocalDate(@servertime) 
SET @hour = datePart(@servertime, "H") 
IF @Hour >= 6 AND @hour <= 18 THEN 
SET @flag = True
 ELSE RaiseError ("Outside operating bussiness hours", true) 
ENDIF 
]%%
```

You will use the same math in the `IF` statement to compare the system time, set system time. You will need to create a DE with the Email address field, the subscriber key, and a `LAST SENT` field. The field will be nullable. An `IF THEN` statement will need to be created. `IF` the value for the last sent is < the specified date `THEN Raiseerror ("Too soon")`.

You will also need to create a script that will write the last sent date value into the DE. Something like a lookup with `SET @LastSent = NOW()`

=)